# Creating a chart in VBA with 2 different Types

Tags: vba, excel

This is probably a basic question, but I have been having a hard time find a good solution for my issue.

I am trying to create a chart programmatically in VBA. The chart needs to have 3 series, with 2 series being xlColumnStacked and 1 series being xlColumnClustered. The idea is to have 1 series being of the xlColumnClustered type, while the other two are stacked. This will result a side by side comparison of the two columns.

Is this possible?

I have tried changing each series type, however the result is the entire chart type will change based on the last series that was changed. (e.g. -> Last series added is xlStacked, all three series are stacked)

I am using Excel 2007 and the embedded VBA macro editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you do this manually through the UI? Is what you're doing in code logically the same as you do in the UI? Using the UI, you need to select the specific series whose type you want to change. Are you doing this in code rather than setting the type of the whole chart?

For anything to do with Excel charts, I would recommend [John Peltier's site](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts)

Comment: I actually can not get this working through the UI (Assuming by UI you mean just using EXCEL). If you have a three series chart, select a single series and changing the type will change it for the entire chart in this case. (E.G. I have a all three stacked and want 1 of the series in a seperate column, so I make that series a Clustered Column, now all three series are clustered columns.) 
Edit: 
I am doing this in VBA code, just because of the dynamics of the data.

Comment: Looking at the site, the Stacked Cluster chart is pretty close to what I wanted. I am not prepared to purchase anything, but this tells me its not a quick easy fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Stackoverflow's contributers. I have found different parts(answers) and put em together. I had 2 series and tried to put em same chart with different type.

```
    Set Chrt = ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    Set s1 = Chrt.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    Set s2 = Chrt.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With Chrt
        .'this part chart part'
    End With
    With s1
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("c3:c24")
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("b3:b24")
        .HasDataLabels = True
        .AxisGroup = xlPrimary
    End With
    With s2
        .ChartType = xlLineStacked
        .AxisGroup = xlSecondary
        .Values = ActiveSheet.Range("d3:d24")
        .XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("b3:b24")
        .HasDataLabels = True
    End With
```

This is my solution and it worked. P.S. Im using excel 2007